# Check if string contains non digit characters

Tags: bash, grep

How can I check if a given string contains non numeric characters, examples :

```
x11z returns > 0
x$1 also returns > 0
1111~ also returns > 0
```

By character I mean everything not between `0-9`. I saw similar threads but non of them talks about "non 0-9"  except they show if its `a-z` or `A-Z`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use a negated character class:

```
grep [^0-9]
```

This will match any non-numeric character, and not strings composed of only digits.

Comment: can we use a character class, `[:digit:] `?

Answer (score 8):

Just by using `bash` pattern matching:

```
[[ "$MY_VAR" =~ ^[^0-9]+$ ]] && echo "no digit in $MY_VAR"
```

Comment: do you need the ^ and $ ? If you match any non digit, it's a failure.

Comment: what does `=~` mean?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
if [[ "xf44wd" =~ [0-9]+ ]]; then
    echo "contains $?"
    else
    echo "does no contains $?"
fi
```

or

```
if [[ ! "xf44wd" =~ [0-9]+ ]]; then
    echo "does not contains $?"
    else
    echo "contains $?"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Most of these suggestions return true if the first character is a digit, but don't find errors within the string.  The function below returns true if the entire string is digits, false if any non-digits are detected in the string.

```
function isdigit () {
   [ $# -eq 1 ] || return 1;
   [[ $1 = *[^0-9]* ]] && return 1
   return 0
}
```

Comment: And then you could use something like `if isdigit $1; then echo "is digit"; else echo "nop"; fi`

Answer (score 1):

Another option, a bash "containment" check

```
[[ "xf4fgh" = *[^0-9]* ]]
echo $?
0
[[ "1234" = *[^0-9]* ]]
echo $?
1
```